# Can you have button inside a tag

Tags: html, css, django

So my problem is that I have those 2 buttons inside this card and when i click them it redirects to a link which the card itself is redirecting, so can i make this work?

```
<a class="panel-product-div-a" href="{{ item.get_absolute_url }}">


    <div style="color: {{ item.checks_color }}" class="p-checks">
      <p>{{ item.checks|safe|linebreaks }}</p>
    </div>
    <span>
      <img {% if item.image %} src="{{ item.image.url }}" {% else %} nop {% endif %} alt="ehm..">
    </span>
    <h1 class="mdh2">{{ item.title }}</h1>


    <div class="panel-button-div">
      <button onclick="window.location.href='{{ item.get_add_to_cart_url }}'"
        class="btn btn-lg btn-primary panel-btn">To cart</button>
      <button onclick="window.location.href='{{ item.get_absolute_url }}'"
        class="btn btn-lg btn-light panel-btn">More info</button>
    </div>


    <div class="con-div">
      {% if item.discount_price %}
      <h1 class="mdh1-discount">
        {{ item.price }}€
      </h1>
      <h1 class="mdh1">
        {{ item.discount_price }}€
      </h1>
      {% else %}
      <h1 class="mdh1">
        {{ item.price }}€
      </h1>
      {% endif %}
    </div>
  </a>
```

[image]

Comment: you basicly cannot have a clikable element inside another clickable element. You have to think this another way.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus yes it is possible if you make use of `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I agree with you that changing the HTML structure would be a better choice (no buttons inside <a> tag). But I was just telling you that a solution exists and is doing the job in this specific case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) :

```html
<button onclick="event.preventDefault();window.location.href='{{ item.get_add_to_cart_url }}'"
        class="btn btn-lg btn-primary panel-btn">To cart</button>
```

Here is a full working example :

```
<html>

<body>
    <a href="card_link">
        <p>My Card text</p>
        <button onclick="event.preventDefault();window.location.href='button_link'">button</button>
    </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Someone downvoted my question without any explanations. My solution is perfectly working, I tested it before posting my answer.

Comment: Yo man ty so much it worked like a charm, saved much time <3

Answer (score 0):

You said

> when i click them it redirects to a link which the card itself is redirecting

do you need the link to be there in the card itself? How about you try removing the link that the card redirects to and then the button links will become accessible.

Otherwise, if you have access to the css, using the [z-index](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) style helps to move certain elements to the front or to the back, so you could give the buttons a higher z-index which will bring them in front of the card.